# Apache Commons XMLConfiguration- How to Get an Object by Attribute Name?

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons, xml-configuration

I am using `org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration` to read the an XML configuration file in my Java code. My XML has the following format:

```xml
<items>
    <item name = "cherry">
        <colour >red</colour >
    </item>

    <item name = "apple">
        <colour >green</colour >
    </item>
</items>
```

I want to get the `colour` value of an `item` named `'cherry'`.
I have tried this:

```java
config.getString("items.item[@name=cherry].colour");
```

But it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: What about config.getString("items.item[@name=/"cherry/"].colour");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Code [Thrill weblog](http://www.code-thrill.com/2012/05/configuration-that-rocks-with-apache.html), I found that I need to set the expression engine to `XPath` by `config.setExpressionEngine(new XPathExpressionEngine());`

which needs the `commons-jxpath` library.

Then I can get the result using XPath like this:

```java
config.getString("items/item[@name='cherry']/colour");
```

Comment: It is config.getString("items/item[name='cherry']/colour") and you can find the same in Thrill weblog link.